# Change different data sources in Pivot Tables in the Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet in Excel with pivot tables and have different data sources. Is there a way to change the data source using VBA?

For example old data source to new data source:

**List** to **NewList**

**Sales** to **NewSales**

Comment: Sure. Have you tried anything so far? (e.g. the macro recorder).

Comment: I tried macro recorder, and yes, it worked fine. I'm just wondering if is there a simplest way?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the code you're working with?